# Looking for an efficient way to build and parse string without GC

Tags: c#, parsing, serial-port

I am trying to figure out if there is a more efficient way than what I'm doing now to build up a message coming in on a serial port and validate it is the right message before I parse it.  A complete message starts with a $ and ends with a CR/LF.  I use an event handler to get the characters as they show up at the serial port so the message will not necessarily come in as one complete block.  Just to confuse things, there are a bunch of other messages that come in on the serial port that don't necessarily start with a $ or end with a CR/LF.  I want to see those but not parse them.  I understand that concatenating strings is probably not a good idea so I use a StringBuilder to build the message then I use a couple of .ToString() calls to make sure I've got the right message to parse.  Do the .ToString calls generate much garbage?  Is there a better way?

I'm not a particularly experienced programmer so thanks for the help.

```
    private void SetText(string text)
    {
        //This is the original approach
        //this.rtbIncoming.Text += text;

        //First post the raw data to the console rtb
        rtbIncoming.AppendText(text);

        //Now clean up the text and only post messages to the CPFMessages rtb that start with a $ and end with a LF
        incomingMessage.Append(text);

        //Make sure the message starts with a $
        int stxIndex = incomingMessage.ToString().IndexOf('$');
        if (stxIndex == 0)
        { }
        else
        {
            if (stxIndex > 0)
                incomingMessage.Remove(0, stxIndex);
        }

        //If the message is terminated with a LF:   1) post it to the CPFMessage textbox, 
        //                                          2) remove it from incomingMessage,
        //                                          3) parse and display fields
        int etxIndex = incomingMessage.ToString().IndexOf('\n');
        if (etxIndex >= 0)
        {
            rtbCPFMessages.AppendText(incomingMessage.ToString(0, etxIndex));
            incomingMessage.Remove(0, etxIndex);
            parseCPFMessage();
        }
    }
```

Comment: As you use a serial port (not the fastest devices) and you process "small" strings, don't worry about garbage collection. Some GC problems occurs when allocating/disposing large memory blocks what is not the case

Answer (score 1):

> Do the .ToString calls generate much garbage?

Every time you call `ToString()`, you get a new `String` object instance. Whether that's "much garbage" depends on your definition of "much garbage" and what you do with those instances.

> Is there a better way?

You can inspect the contents of `StringBuilder` directly, but you'll have to write your own methods to do that. You could use state-machine-based techniques to monitor the stream of data.

Whether any of that would be "better" than your current implementation depends on a number of factors, including but not limited to:

- Are you seeing a specific performance issue now?
- If so, what specific performance goal are you trying to achieve?
- What other overhead exists in your code?

The first question above is very important. Your first priority should be code that *works*. If your code is working now, and does not have a specific performance issue that you know you need to solve, then you can safely ignore the GC issues for now. .NET's GC system is designed to perform well in scenarios just like this one, and usually will. Only in unusual situations would you need to do extra work to solve a performance problem here.

Without [a good, *minimal*, *complete* code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that clearly illustrates the above and any other relevant issues, it would not be possible to say with any specificity whether there is in fact "a better way". If the above answers don't provide the information you're looking for, consider [improving your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so that it is not so broad.